# How to create an object for Jmeter class (for ex :SampleResult ..etc)

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to execute the below code in Jmeter jsr223 Postpro for a simple sampler for which the response time is always > 2 milli secs ,but i am getting the answer as 0 .i know i can use prev.getTime() & it works , but why not like the below ?..Just curious.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;    
SampleResult sr = new SampleResult();    
long time = sr.getTime();
log.info("Response time is -"+time);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new result. This result isn't connected to any request and therefore initialize time with 0 value.

`prev` holds last request including its time.

Answer (score 0):

There is `prev` shorthand which stands for the parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), if you want to print the time taken by the [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) to the [*jmeter.log*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) file - you should rather be using `prev` instead of creating a new instance of the SampleResult class

so your code needs to be amended as follows:

```
long time = prev.getTime();
log.info("Response time is -"+time);
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)